# Jargon term for dividing blocking code up into asynchronous callbacks

Tags: asynchronous, blocking, event-driven

I seem to recall hearing a term for breaking up long-running synchronous code into chunks that are incrementally evaluated over multiple callbacks on the event-queue (to avoid blocking). Does such a term exist? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

The tags on your post indicate you're already familiar with "ansynchronous", "non-blocking", and "event-driven".  The only other terms that come to mind are "deferred processing" and "threaded" but those have different mechanics and meanings, and it is important that they are not confused.